# How to save generated qr Code in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

I have generated QR code using "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode

Now I want to save the generated image in my local drive. How can I do it?

```
 public function qr($id)
{

    $data = Ticket::get()->find($id);
    $image = \QrCode::format('png')
                     ->merge('img/t.jpg', 0.1, true)
                     ->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')
                     ->generate('A simple example of QR code!');
    return response($image)->header('Content-type','image/png');

    return view('qrCode', compact('qrData', $qrData));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my local drive"? Do you want to store that image on your server? Do you want to download it?

Comment: in laravel "public\img" @NicoHaase

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i don't know what to do next. I get QR code in my url. Now I don't know how to save it. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
$image = \QrCode::format('png')
                 ->merge('img/t.jpg', 0.1, true)
                 ->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')
                 ->generate('A simple example of QR code!');
$output_file = '/img/qr-code/img-' . time() . '.png';
Storage::disk('local')->put($output_file, $image); //storage/app/public/img/qr-code/img-1557309130.png
```

Comment: Thanks. this does the job!!

Comment: how can show this image in laravel admin org in show details and edit form view?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi use img tag to show the image.

Comment: @TeachMe means i need to customize my controllers in app/admin/controllers/MyController in show or grid method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for public

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($output_file, $image); //storage/app/public/img/qr-code/img-1557309130.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = new ModelName();

$path = '/img/qr-code/img/';

if(!\File::exists(public_path($path))) {
    \File::makeDirectory(public_path($path));
}

$file_path = $path . time() . '.png';
$image = \QrCode::format('png')
                 ->merge('img/t.jpg', 0.1, true)
                 ->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')
                 ->generate('A simple example of QR code!', $file_path)

$data->field_name = $file_path;
$data->save();
```

`I hope this will help you, it works fine for me`